# @Priority annotation usage in Jersey Filter

Tags: java, jersey

So I have four jersey filters, for example:

```
FilterOne
FilterTwo
FilterThree
FilterFour
```

and I want to set @Priority in the same sequence. And my question is if I put for FilterTwo @Priority(2), for FilterThree @Priority(3) etc. Do I need to set priority for the first filter? And is this the right way to set them?

Edit:

Found what I need https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/filters-ordering.html

Answer (score 1):

For extensibility, you probably want to have more space between filters so you can later add more filters between existing filters, for example start with priority 10 and increment by 10

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for [`Priorities`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html). You will see:

> JAX-RS components that belong to the same priority class (same integer value) are executed in an implementation-defined manner. By default, when the @Priority annotation is absent on a component, for which a priority should be applied, the [USER](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#USER) priority value is used.

The `USER` holds a value of [5000](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.ws.rs.Priorities.USER). The lower the value, the higher the precedence. So if you leave off the `@Priority`, the filter will be called after there other filters, as 2 and 3 are less than 5000.